# Morphism of flat schemes over Artinian local rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $A$ is a local artinian $k$-algebra, $X_1,X_2$ are finite type schemes flat over $A$, and $f:X_1\rightarrow X_2$ is a morphism over $A$ that is an isomorphism after restricting to closed fibers, then $f$ is an isomorphism.

This was proved here in the case that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are affine.

I am interested in automorphisms of $X$ over $A$ which we know to be a subset of the group of endomorphism of $X$ over $A$ which restrict to automorphisms of the fiber $X_0$.

Let $Aut(X/X_0)$ represent the group of automorphism of $X$ which restrict to the identity on $X_0$.

It seems like I should be able to act on $Aut(X/X_0)$ with $Aut(X_0)$ to recover $Aut(X)$.

Is this ever the case?

Here I am assuming that I have a local description of elements in $Aut(X/X_0)$ in terms of local coordinates on $X_0$. It seems like I could just pullback the automorphism in $Aut(X/X_0)$ via automorphism in $Aut(X_0)$.

Comment: Use https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04DE to reduce to the affine case..

Comment: What do you mean by $X_0$?

Comment: $X_0= X \times_A k$.

Comment: @RijulSaini I appreciate you pointing out this theorem but I don't quite understand how knowing that any automorphism is affine helps me get a handle on the automorphism group of $X$.